# randomForest() machine learning in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am exploring with the function `randomforest()` in R and several articles I found all suggest using a similar logic as below, where the response variable is column 30 and independent variables include everthing else except for column 30:

```
dat.rf <- randomForest(dat[,-30], 
                      dat[,30], 
                      proximity=TRUE, 
                      mtry=3,
                      importance=TRUE,
                      do.trace=100,
                      na.action = na.omit)
```

When I try this, I got the following error messages:

**Error in randomForest.default(dat[, -30], dat[, 30], proximity = TRUE,  : 
NA not permitted in predictors
In addition: Warning message:
In randomForest.default(dat[, -30], dat[, 30], proximity = TRUE,  :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?**

However, I was able to get it to work when I listed the independent variables one by one while keeping all the other parameters the same.

```
dat.rf <- randomForest(as.factor(Y) ~X1+ X2+ X3+ X4+ X5+ X6+ X7+ X8+ X9+ X10+......,                          
                      data=dat
                      proximity=TRUE,
                      mtry=3,
                      importance=TRUE,
                      do.trace=100,
                      na.action = na.omit)
```

Could someone help me debug the simplier command where I don't have to list each predictor one by one?

Answer (score 4):

The error message gives you a clue to two problems:

1. First, you need to remove any row that has a `NA` anywhere. Removing NA should be easy enough and I'll leave you that one as an exercise.
2. It looks like you need to do classification (which predicts a response which only has one of a few discrete levels), rather than regression (which predicts a continuous response). If the response is continuous, `randomForest()` will automatically apply regression.

So, how do you force `randomForest()` to use classification?As you noticed in your first try, `randomForest` allows you to give data as predictors and response data, not just using the formula style. To force `randomForest()` to apply classification, make sure that the value you are trying to predict (the response, or `dat[,30]`) is a factor. Remember to explicitly identify the $x$ and $y$ arguments. This is easy to do:

```
 randomForest(x = dat[,-30],
              y = factor(dat[,30]),
              ...)
```

This way your output can only take one of the levels given in y.

This is all buried in the description of the arguments $x$ and $y$: see `?help`.

Comment: Thanx!! I did notice the error message about NA and it went away when I removed the NA observations. I was curious though, when I called out the X variables one by one the my 2nd command, it didn't complain about the NA observations (I did go back to the original dataset that still included the NA observations).  I will definitely try your suggestions, thanx much!!